# How do I get Photoshop CC 2017 to recognize my second AMD VGA video card?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, adobe-photoshop

I tried reinstalling it and the driver but Photoshop CC 2017 will not recognize my second AMD VGA video card. Obviously it’s very slow to work like this. Any clue how to solve it?

- Latest driver.
- I reset my preferences files.
- I clean uninstall the driver: My Intel HD Graphics 4000 **is** recognized.

  - (which I actively use for 4th and 5th monitors)
- Then I reinstall main VGA driver and it appears gray again as on the image.
- Photoshop doesn’t like that I have 2 different VGA card (1 dedicated, 1 integrated), but that is preposterous, I can’t be the only one who prefers to work with multiple monitors, more than what 1 card supports.

[image]

Comment: Rebooted since?

Comment: Yes. I read in other threads that PS doesn't like multi-vga... But this doesn't crash, simply greyed out.

Comment: ah, didn't know that about VGA... but I haven't had a VGA monitor in 10 years, so I'm a bit out of touch

Comment: I meant multiple VGA vards (discrete and integrated), not the connection type. I utilize all kinds of outputs to run 3 to 5 monitors (HDMI, DP, DVI, even a VGA cable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I have so far stems from the idea that if I don't connect or enable any monitor on the secondary (integrated) VGA, then PS detects and uses the main VGA. I already use [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) for managing multi-monitor profiles.

I created a profile that enables only the monitors connected to the main VGA. I switch to this with a global hotkey just while Photoshop starts. Then I immediately switch back to the normal 4 monitor layout (2 on each VGA). Photoshop continues to work fine and gets accelerated by my main VGA as I need it.

If I don't close Photoshop then this can work indefinitely. I got tired of having it open all the time and seeing it on the taskbar. I have 32GB RAM that I don't really max out therefore my PC could handle it being open all the time, so I searched for a solution to minimize it to tray.

That software I use, DisplayFusion has a side-feature of minimizing anything to tray and removing it from the taskbar. I created a keyboard shortcut, so when I'm done with Photoshop I just hit a convenient keyboard shortcut and it goes to the tray. If I open a PSD or try to run PS again, it doesn't do anything fancy (does not even activate), it just opens the file silently in the background until I re-activate it from the tray.

Answer (score 6):

From Photoshop FAQ [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-cc-gpu-card-faq.html) you can see that:

> Does Photoshop take advantage of more than one graphics processor or
>   graphics card?
>
> Photoshop currently doesn't take advantage of more than one graphics
>   processor. Using two graphics cards does not enhance Photoshop's
>   performance.
>
> Multiple graphics cards with conflicting drivers can cause problems
>   with graphics processor accelerated features in Photoshop.
>
> For best results, connect two (or more) monitors into one graphics
>   card.
>
> If you have to use more than one graphics card, make sure that they
>   are the same make and model. Otherwise, crashes and other problems can
>   occur in Photoshop.

And [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/troubleshoot-gpu-graphics-card.html#Troubleshoot) there is troubleshooter for graphic cards problems, but the recommended approach is to disable the less powerful card and work with just one.

And too, in the list of the unsupported graphic cards you can see:

> Unsupported card series
>   The following card series are no longer being tested and are not
>   officially supported in Photoshop:
>
> AMD/ATI 100, 200, 3000, and 4000 series
>   nVidia GeForce 7000, 8000, 9000, 100, 200, 300 series
>   Older Intel® HD Graphics (for example 2000, 3000, 4000 series) cards
>
> Some GL functionality may be available for these cards, but newer
>   features won't work.

Your intel (default) graphic card is unsupported, so, no game for you.

Comment: If I disable monitors connected to the other vga, start photoshop (it sees my AMD vga), then I reenable the other monitors, everything continues to work fine I can even move it to the other monitor with Intel vga... But why can games and hw accelerated video be moved across monitors without any problems but photoshop straight out refusing to choose the vga of the monitor it was started on, without this trickery? Makes no sense. If I disable AMD, it works fine on the Intel too.

Comment: Because Adobe engineers are lazy? While games run in the best graphic card available, Photoshop runs in the first one, being that the internal one

Comment: I would be fine if it ran on any of them, even on the integrated. But it does not detect either, when both are in use. If I disable any one of them, it works fine.

Comment: "Photoshop currently doesn't take advantage of more than one graphics processor. Using two graphics cards does not enhance Photoshop's performance." What about gimp?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in Adobe Forum, Here is the Link

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2284985

Seems you have to add Photoshop CC manually to work with your AMD GPU.

Please note, I'm not AMD user. I have nVidia GeForce and I had to manually set the preferred GPU for my Apps/Games in nVidia Control Panel.

You could also try by **Right-Clicking on Adobe Photoshop** and Select desired Graphics Card to run the application as show in the below image

[image]

Comment: That looks good for Nvidia, but AMD doesn't have that. AMD driver has evolved and it looks different than on those screenshots. It made no difference if I added it as a known 3D software in the control center.